# changing destination folder of resources in maven

Tags: java, maven, deployment

I copied pasted the following snippet taken from the [doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) in my pom.xml

```
  <plugin>
    <!-- <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/resources</outputDirectory>
          <resources>                                        
            <resource>
              <directory>${basedir}/template</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>             
          </resources>   
        </configuration>            
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

but I get the following message when I try to trigger the deployment:

```
$ mvn resources:copy-resources 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< org.test:myproject >------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:copy-resources (default-cli) @ myproject ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.440 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-26T12:30:59+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:copy-resources (default-cli) on project myproject: The parameters 'resources', 'outputDirectory' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:copy-resources are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
```

here's my dir structures:

```
./resources
./template
./template/test.txt
./pom.xml
```

How can I change the destination folder of resources? why maven did not parse the configuration directives in the plugin?

Comment: First why do you want to change the destination folder because the resources directory is intended to be packaged into the resulting artifact? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: just for learning purpose. I had some external files to parameterize and my goal was getting the job done only using maven. I know it's not the right tool but I wanted to force the project configuration to accomplish extra chores. Anyway the main reason I studied maven was to parameterize source code at building time, namely resolving variable at building time, something like -D at launch time. Not sure if using preprocessing was feasible

Comment: If you really need to do some parameterizing of source code there are better solutions like: https://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/

Comment: Yep I used templating-maven-plugin for the java source. but i need to parameterize some data files that's the reason I used resource plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full command syntax to execute a particular maven goal is :

```
mvn <plugin>:<goal>@<executionId>
```

When executionId is not specified , it is equal to `default-cli` by default.

Now you execute `mvn resources:copy-resources` which is equivalent to `mvn resources:copy-resources@default-cli` but your `pom.xml` does not defined this execution id for this goal. So it complains some parameters are missing and not configured well.

As you define the execution id to be `copy-resources` , which means you should execute :

```
mvn resources:copy-resources@copy-resources
```

Or as you bind this goal to the `validate` phase , that means you can also simply execute it by :

```
mvn validate
```

Comment: This simply does not answer the question...

Comment: why ? would you please explain ?  i am answering OP 's question `why maven did not parse the configuration directives in the plugin`  when he executes `mvn resources:copy-resources`. I then provide my advices what command that he should use such that the configuration he configured in pom.xml can take effect

Comment: First you haven't read the headline: `changing destination folder of resources in maven`... second `The parameters 'resources', 'outputDirectory' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:copy-resources are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]` this error message shows that the problem is not the command line call and you haven't given any kind of advice how to change that..... furthermore using an explicit call to a goal of a plugin is usually not a good idea...better keep it in the life cycle..

Comment: Well. Yes or no. Need OP to clarify what he want to do . But it seems to me that he just want to use `maven-resources-plugin` to copy files from template folder to another destination folder and he is asking why executing `mvn resources:copy-resources` does not work given this `pom.xml`, and asking how to change the destination folder that the files in `template` folder will be copied into. I think my answer should be helpful to him for the first question. Thanks.

Comment: My goal was changing the default directories structure and applying some parameters substitution in the java sources and resources files. I managed the parameters substitution in the java code using templating-maven-plugin but I couldn't get the resources stuff done. That's my first go with maven and I had read only the introduction part of the manual. I need to deep more into the manual to understand the build life cycle and the phases. Your answer was helpful. Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: I found the id mechanism a little incosistent. Maybe some defaults are encapsulated directly in the plugin code.
if you add a configuration for the resource plugin with a goal copy-resources and an id=default-cli and launch the command mvn resources:resources it executes the goal copy-resources and not the goal resources and it considers the plugin.configuration.resources not the build.resources. I expected to find a default-goal set as default-resources in the goal resources:resources but there isn't. Pretty strange

Comment: Moreover if you redefine the goal resources whith the id=default-resources and phase process-resources it does not copy on the execution.configuration.outputDirectory but in the build.outputDirectory.